# We need a way to close duplicate Doc topic requests

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

People are filling queues up with requests (some of them good) but there's a problem in that I can't flag requests as dupes of one another. I can only flag it as a dupe if someone has already created the topic.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is going to happen a lot where a topic is effectively a subset of another language. I just came across an example where someone requested a topic for class modules in [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) when there is already a topic request in [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba). As class modules are generic to all of [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) they should be covered there and **only** excel-specific parts of the language such as certain objects or data types should be covered in the [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag.

This is one of the smaller languages being covered in documentation, so it's probably best this gets 'nipped in the bud' before it causes major problems in areas like jQuery vs. JavaScript that have a much bigger following.

Perhaps some general information about this in the documentation tour would help, or a placeholder/prompt in the 'request topic' textbox?

*[follow on question posted here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329348/synonyms-on-documentation)*