# Reorganizing documentation sections regarding Apple technologies

Tags: discussion, documentation

Right now, we've got these sections:

- Objective-C
- Swift
- iOS
- Cocoa (meaning: macOS)

The problem is that there's a lot of overlap. For example, in Objective-C, someone requested a topic about Grand Central Dispatch but that's not specific to Objective-C, neither to any of the other existing sections. On the other side, topics like NSUserDefaults are covered in several sections ([iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/1601/nsnotificationcenter#t=201607241547553832013), [Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/260/userdefaults#t=20160724154826367503), [Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/objective-c/804/nsuserdefaults#t=201607241548403830954)).

This is a waste of resources, IMHO. Thus, I propose that we reorganize the sections like this:

- Objective-C: Only topics about the language itself. How to create and use classes, properties, memory management, low-level API, etc. pp.
- Swift: Also only topics about language features like optionals, memory management, structs, etc. pp.
- iOS: APIs specific to iOS and maybe tvOS. That's mostly UI stuff but also things like UIDevice and other platform specific topics.
- macOS: APIs specific to macOS. Also mostly about UI, but also topics about things like writing kernel extensions or other macOS-only topics.
- Apple Technologies (Working Title): Covers APIs and technologies common to all platforms and are used in Objective-C and Swift (or C). Things like NSUserDefaults, NSNotificationCenter, Grand Central Dispatch, threading, etc. pp. Examples can be in either Objective-C or Swift since it's about the technologies, but preferably examples would be provided in both languages.

To me, that seems to be the most effective way of avoiding duplication and overlap. But a catchy name for the common-to-all-platforms section would be needed.

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: @NicolBolas I realize that's a bit idealistic. Maybe someone has better idea on how to tackle the issue? Since Documentation is still young, now's a chance to fix this. Once there's thousands of entries in each section we won't change it.

Comment: I prefer good doses of realisms once in a while, in fact I like realisms all the time.

Comment: I've [asked a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329171/3764814) about this issue, with C#/.NET as an example. It's more widespread than I thought.

Comment: @DarkDust: "*I realize that's a bit idealistic.*" It's not so much a question of idealism; it's just that we lack the tools to actually do it. Unlike for example Mediawiki, one person can't just download the pages, rearrange things, and upload them all back. The movement of all the examples have to be approved individually, and it all has to be done through the UI. Plus, there's no effective means to tell people which things should go where.

Comment: Highly in favor. One technical objection is that I don't believe there _can be_ an "Apple Technologies" tag, because they are tied to existing tags on Q&A.

Comment: You many also be interested in [Where can we discuss guidelines for documentation on a per tag basis?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329173)

Comment: Well, Apple Technologies is largely "Cocoa" … and what's currently in Cocoa and meaning macOS should be moved to a new MacOS tag then?

Comment: @bwoebi: Not quite, we distinguish between "Cocoa" meaning macOS APIs and "Cocoa Touch" meaning iOS/tvOS APIs.

Comment: @DarkDust but they still overlap a lot, at least for Foundation? … Well… then maybe rename it to foundation?

Comment: I don't know how much action this will get, (and I've never been an RO before, so eeek) but what the hay: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118148/apple-docs-organization

Comment: @JoshCaswell There's a separate [osx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx) tag for macOS, so Cocoa _could_ map to "Apple Technologies", whether or not it contains Cocoa Touch topics also.

Comment: For the Objective-C/Swift issue, I was really hoping something like [this](http://nshipster.com/cloudkit/#subscriptions) would be implemented.

Comment: That was mentioned as being planned, @tktsubota; I saw it yesterday but can't figure out where right now. I think it was in one of the original two "Warlords" posts.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I mentioned it in the "Update-en-ing": http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319319/documentation-the-update-en-ing#comment324352_319319.

Comment: It was a staff member, @tktsubota; I found it: "What's to come" section down the bottom of [the public beta announcement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328405/).

Comment: I think the intent is good, but it doesn't really facilitate terminology differences between Swift/Objective C -- e.g., NSUserDefaults versus UserDefaults -- or functionality differences between platforms. An API may share some things in common, yet not every method, property or feature is available on every platform.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328520/we-need-a-way-to-close-duplicate-doc-topic-requests

Comment: @DarkDust I agree with your general idea. Regarding cocoa/cocoa-touch I have already made an edit (not yet accepted) to the cocoa tag introduction suggesting that it covers both cocoa and cocoa-touch to avoid duplication. I recommend we try to direct most shared topics in this direction. I understand that the ability to move whole topics between tags is on the devs to-do list, which would make tidying up easier.

Comment: I would also recommend that larger common APIs get their own tags and this is already happening, e.g. core-data and sprite-kit.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a modified version:

- Objective-C: Language-specific
- Swift: Language-specific, but *also* the Swift Standard Library
- iOS
- tvOS: tvOS exclusive features or caveats. Explain how the tvOS docs are for tvOS exclusive features, and how it is heavily based on iOS. Direct users to iOS docs from the Getting Started page.

  - Example: [Focus](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwiththeAppleTVRemote.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015241-CH5-SW5)
  - Another example: [Touch detection in SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793051/how-to-detect-touches-in-sprite-kit-tvos)
- watchOS (mapped from [watchkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watchkit) or [watch-os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watch-os))
- macOS (mapped from [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx))
- Apple Technologies (mapped from [cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa)): IMO "Apple Technologies" is fine, it's to the point and makes sense. Another possible option is "Apple Frameworks". Since documentation tags have to have a respective SO tag, Cocoa seems like the logical choice here.

You may have to explain on Objective-C and Swift's getting started pages to look at the other tags' documentation if they're looking for that.

Comment: Note, on Q&A, [tag:cocoa] means specifically the OS X umbrella framework; that is, it does not include Cocoa Touch. But that doesn't seem insurmountable.

Comment: How about [tag:foundation]? That covers most of that stuff. Also, GCD could conceivably be its own tag (it’s OSS).

Comment: watchOS is *far more* than [tag:watchkit] and shouldn't be mapped from one specific framework. Just to give two examples, it also includes ClockKit (complications), and WatchConnectivity.

Comment: @PetahChristian Is there a watchOS tag? [tag:watchos]

Comment: Yes, but it's got a hyphen. Also, the general [tag:watch-os] tag is mostly used for watchOS 1, and often isn't used in general for [tag:watch-os-2] or [tag:watch-os-3] questions.

Comment: @JF Yes, that could work. However, there are other frameworks like CloudKit, EventKit, AVFoundation, etc. that have to be included also.

Comment: I don't think the "Apple Technologies" section can be mapped to a tag. Apple seems to call the shared codebase "CocoaCore", at least internally. It's very unlikely to have someone ask a `cocoa-core` question, however.

Comment: @Siguza "Apple Technologies" will simply be the friendly name. Using Cocoa as it's mapped tag _should_ be okay.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree that there's a lot of overlap, I'm not convinced that the way to handle it is to group common APIs under an "Apple Technologies" (or "Foundation") tag.

**A common topic would have too much to read through or ignore:**

Since there's no current way to filter a topic by language or version or platform, a user would be forced to read (or to write) a really long example that would need to include both language-specific syntax (Swift 2.x, Swift 3.0, Objective-C) as well as platform-specific differences.

**A common topic would include features or examples that may not apply to a platform:**

For example, while iOS and tvOS share a lot in common, one platform uses touch while the other uses focus. watchOS is very different from iOS and is missing many methods and properties that you'd find available on iOS.

I think it would be a negative experience if the user read some "Foundation" example, then went to try it out and discovered that that feature either wasn't supported, or it behaved differently, on tvOS or watchOS, than it did on iOS or macOS.

**A common topic may not be where a user first looks for information:**

When I go to look something up, I *already* know what platform, language, and version that I'll be supporting.

So, my interest is very specific, such as *"Show me how to support gestures on watchOS (using Swift)."*

While I could sort out glossing over the Objective-C syntax, I wouldn't want to have to read about how gestures work on iOS. I really want to learn about the specific features or nuances that pertain to watchOS gestures.

That's why a common article about any technology that's supported on 2, 3, or 4 different platforms, probably wouldn't be a good approach.

Comment: [bwoebi mentioned this in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31892226#31892226), and I agreed that I can't see anything wrong with cross-references. The iOS section on a topic would mostly contain _what's different_, and refer the reader to the umbrella Doc for the common stuff.

Comment: a) Since iOS is the most feature-rich of the three platforms, it seems that it would contain a lot of details about what's different. Surely the umbrella doc isn't meant to be the least common subset, as it may be quite short, compared to iOS?  b) More significantly, wouldn't it be more of an inconvenience if a user has to read both the umbrella doc and the platform-specific doc, to then get a full understanding of a topic? c) It also seems like more trouble/work moving newly contributed info back and forth, since there would be more opportunity for people to contribute to the wrong tag docs.